# Upper Semicontinuity of Spectral Radius

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let X be an Banach Algebra. Suppose $M_n\rightarrow M$ in norm topology. Show that lim sup$\sigma(M_n)\le \sigma(M)$.

By a theorem of Gelfand, $\sigma(M)=lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} |M^k|^{\frac{1}{k}}$. Do I need to use this formula?